# How can I make webpack treeshake my ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have followed every guide out there for turning on tree shaking in webpack 4 but webpack still bundles code from a NPM module that I have set up to be treeshaken. How can I enable treeshaking and not include particular code in my web app?

[Full source code in GitHub repo](https://github.com/jared-hexagon/treeshaking-test)

I have a CRA (create-react-app) that imports a NPM module I created to test it that looks like this:

```
package
  index.mjs
  dist
    esm
      components
        image
          index.js
        index.js
      index.js
```

with `package.json` like this:

```
  "main": "index",
  "module": "index.jsm",
  "sideEffects": false,
```

that transpiles using babel with babelrc like:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "@babel/react",
    "@babel/flow"
  ]
}
```

I have 3 React components: `image`, `avatar` (that imports `image`) and `login-button` that has this es6 code:

```
import React from 'react'

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + "<div>This is a side effect and should never have happened</div>"

export default () => <button>Login</button>
```

The index file for the NPM es6 module:

```
import * as lib from './dist/esm'

export default lib
```

In the CRA's `app.js` I have:

```
import TreeshakingTestModule from 'treeshaking-test-module'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TreeshakingTestModule.Avatar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**When I `npm start` it builds and renders the avatar but I also see the message.**

Note that `login-button` is never used however the default export of my NPM package which does export the component is imported, however I read tutorials that explained that even default exports and re-exports should still work with tree shaking if what is exported is never used.

What is happening? What am I doing wrong?

[Full source code in GitHub repo](https://github.com/jared-hexagon/treeshaking-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, webpack three shakes by analysing imports statically, not by reading your code. You cannot expect webpack to realize you're only using `Avatar` from `TreeshakingTestModule`.

So you need to declare what you want to use at `import` level, by using named imports and exports:

```
import {Avatar} from 'treeshaking-test-module'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Avatar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So webpack knows you're only using the `Avatar` export.

This means that `Avatar` needs to be a named export in your `treeshaking-test-module` module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not work. I refactored to use named imports (`index.mjs` re-exports from each component) but it still included my side effect. Code: https://github.com/jared-hexagon/treeshaking-test/compare/import-named

Comment: Nevermind - I was doing `npm start`. Treeshaking is only enabled when building for production (`npm run build`). This works - I did not see the side effect when I used named imports.